# Crawling App Web List Content

Tags: search, sharepoint-addin

I created a SharePoint provider hosted App with Libraries containing documents.

As I tried to search for those documents I got no results. (But I get documents of the host web.)

So as I investigated this problem I found the following thread:
[Is data Inside SharePoint Hosted App searchable?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93885/is-data-inside-sharepoint-hosted-app-searchable)

I am still not sure if it's really not possible?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you have to provision your lists and libraries in the host web in order for them to be discovered and crawled by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is probably due to having a proxy configured in the Farm Search Administration dashboard ([CentralAdmin]/searchfarmdashboard.aspx) and the proxies not knowing how to route non Internet requests. You need to let SharePoint search know to not use the proxies for the AppWeb URLs, by adding a wildcard entry in the URL exceptions list

Check your ULS logs on the crawl server for errors with eventID du54.

Update "Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with:" to add http://[AppPrefix]* (and/or https://[AppPrefix]* if you use SSL sites).

The * must be present as AppWeb URLs are dynamically generated with each new app instance. (I wonder if this is one of the reasons MSFT even have an AppWeb prefix that needs to be defined?).

Note: You can determine the [AppPrefix] from Central Admin 
[CentralAdmin]/_admin/ConfigureAppSettings.aspx